# How to parse more than one string into an int in java

Tags: java, exception, parseint

Ok, so I'm having a lot of trouble with a programming assignment. We are to read information from a text file and format it using certain methods we created. I am able to read information from the first line in the text file fine, but afterwords I get an error. My code is as follows:

```
String name1 = scan.nextLine();
    String name2 = scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();
    int length = name1.length();
    int count = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    while(end != true)
    {

        String check = name1.substring(a,b);
        a++;
        b++;
        count++;
        char z = check.charAt(0);
        if(z == '0' || z == '1' || z == '2' || z == '3' || z == '4' || z == '5' || z == '6' || z == '7' || z == '8' || z == '9')
        {
            end = true;

        }
        if(count == length)
        {
            end = true;

        }
    }
    String number1 = name1.substring(count,length);
    int number01 = Integer.parseInt(number1);
    name1=name1.substring(0, count-1);
    int d = name1.indexOf(" ");
    int length1 = name1.length();
    String name1first = name1.substring(0,d);
    name1first = name1first.trim();
    String name1last = name1.substring(d,length1);
    name1last = name1last.trim();

    System.out.println(name1first);
    System.out.println(name1last);
    System.out.println(number01);


    length = name2.length();
   int  countt = 0;
int  aa = 0;
int  bb = 1;
    while(end != true)
    {

        String check = name2.substring(aa,bb);
        aa++;
        bb++;
        countt++;
        char z = check.charAt(0);
        if(z == '0' || z == '1' || z == '2' || z == '3' || z == '4' || z == '5' || z == '6' || z == '7' || z == '8' || z == '9')
        {
            end = true;

        }
        if(countt == length)
        {
            end = true;

        }
    }
    String number2 = name2.substring(countt,length);
    int number02 = Integer.parseInt(number2);
    name2=name2.substring(0, countt-1);
    d = name2.indexOf(" ");
    int length2 = name2.length();
    String name2first = name2.substring(0,d);
    name2first = name2first.trim();
    String name2last = name2.substring(d,length2);
    name2last = name2last.trim();

    System.out.println(name2first);
    System.out.println(name2last);
    System.out.println(number02);
```

and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Jennifer Sutter 52114"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Salary.main(Salary.java:101)
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what you're doing wrong: you're trying to parse non-numeric text as a number, and that obviously won't work. The solution: don't do this.

Comment: but other than that, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I thought I separated the numeric value from the text value in my code though. That's what the while loop is for

Comment: @user1799156 its alright, you can get rid of that ridiculously hideous while loop code and use Scanner class.

Comment: I'm not sure. Your code is a bit original, including your code formatting, and thus hard to interpret. You might want to consider cleaning it up a bit.

Comment: Most important for you and us is to know what type of data you'll be analyzing in your text file, something we have no knowledge of, as this will affect your code design.

Comment: Well, I figured out the problem, my end boolean was never set back to false for the second while loop. Sorry for the bad formatting, this is due in 45 minutes and I'm kind of in a rush. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

That's but obvious why you're getting that exception:

You're trying to convert "Jennifer Sutter 52114" to an integer.

Solution is to firstly use `try{}catch()` block while trying to call `Integer.parseInt()`.

What I think is you're trying to get that last bit of string and convert it to integer: and since you're using `Scanner` you can `nextInt()` on it like so:

`new Scanner(theStringWhichMightHaveANumber).nextInt();`

Comment: how does that happen though? In the first block of code I do exactly the same thing and it only converts the number into an integer

Comment: @user1799156 I don't have the entire code that you're having to test it with, hence I cannot actually give you a reason for that question!